# Random Position between ranges

Tags: 2d, random, objective-c, platform

Does anyone have a good algorithm for generating a random y position for spawning a block, which takes into account a minimum and maximum height, allowing player to to jump on the block.

Blocks will continually be spawned, so the player must always be able to jump onto the next block, bearing in mind the minimum position which would be the ground, and the maximum which would the players jump height bearing in mind the ceiling

Comment: Blakey87 is obviously beginning game development, if you are going to cast a vote to close, write a comment as to why, don't just vote to close because it is easy.

Comment: @AttackingHobo you are 100% correct and thanks, I come from a web based background (PHP), and this is my first time at trying to create a game, never used objective C before so everything is new to me, I dont normally ask for help but I thought why not

Comment: @AttackingHobo I voted to close because the question basically asks for a way to get a random value between a given `min` and `max`, which is really trivial, as long as you figure out how to get a random value on your system (which is not the question). I think beginners questions are ok, but there's got to be a threshold. Also all the answers given don't provide a solution in plain Objective-C, so no real help there (assuming the OP is really totally new to Objective-C)

Comment: @blakey87: Are the platforms always going up? Or is a lower platform also allowed? If yes, what is the max falling distance? You should be more specific (maybe an image would help) about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This is a real question. There's no point generating a platform that is unreachable. It is trivial, yes, but it is a real question.

Comment: @bummzack: Generating a good random value between two numbers is actually something I see people do wrong _very_ often; usually their results are either biased, or unnecessarily slow.

Comment: Yes my question may bit vague but its not as trivial as simply generating a min-y and max-y pos , I might not knowledgeable in objective C well enough to do this effectively, but I'm 100% a competent programmer to the point that I had already done this myself, I was just looking for a better way of doing it, anyway blocks scroll from left to right, the character must always be able to jump onto a platform, as in if the last position was at n the next platform must have a  maximum of what ever the characters jump potential is, and also a minimum of the lowest possible point/ground level

Comment: I will update my question with the above info just to make it clearer , I'm more of a lurker if I knew this question would cause so much heat,in hindsight I'd remain a lurker, but its all fun and games

Comment: Also Gajet answer is 100% what Im looking for as it accounts for all variables ie the ceiling, I am already able to calculate what @TheCommunistDuc suggests and yes that is a trivial task, I think down voters should rethink their down vote

Comment: @Joe Wreschnig: True, generating good random numbers is not a trivial task. I was not under the impression that the OP was specifically asking for a random generator that is fast and provides a good number distribution... that would probably be another question for itself.

Comment: @bummzack @Communist @AttackingHobo: I think the answers have shown that this question is not trivial.

Comment: @bummzack: There are two problems and you're conflating them - first, generating good random numbers. That's _really_ hard. Second, generating good random numbers between two given values. That's not really hard, but people still screw it up a lot. (Duck's answer is biased, CaseyB's answer confuses noise and randomness, MrXee's answer is unbiased but unnecessarily slow.)

Comment: @blakey87 I re-read your question and wondered how your level will look like. Apparently you're always going up.. but on the other hand you have a ceiling.. so that level will be over quite soon because it can't go up any further?

Comment: @blakey :seems at least you understood what my code did before i explain it more. but even if others didn't understand a code why should they downvote it? they can test the code and see it's working correctly or ask for more explenation! just as I did after reading BlueRaja's answer.

Comment: @bummzack is right, the core of the question is trivial and the question itsself is vague, asker didnt do any research -1

Comment: http://www.xkcd.com/221/ -- I couldn't help myself.

Comment: hehe @nate isn't that under a sony NDA :)

Comment: @maik -- it very well might be. Like I said, I couldn't help myself though.

Comment: @bummzack blocks scroll from left to right at a variable height, I don’t mention anything to do with the player continuously going up do I? the ground becomes the danger zone effectively meaning the player cannot therefore touch the ground ie having to jump on blocks which are scrolling from left to right, I hope this stop yours confusion, @Maik Semder I done research, I already even implemented a random y generator BEFORE asking this question,

Comment: I come to you guys, as I have not been doing game dev for long, I am a web developer through and through, so I was seeing if the way I implemented it was good enough which it wasn’t as there are plenty of posts I found useful. Remember we all have to start someone, just like anything

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You just have to generate some boundaries for the blocks you are going to make, maybe due to the last block or other limitations in your game; for example, if your game has some level of ground, no block should start below ground level. Having those parameters set, it's really easy to create a random number which has all the features you required.

In your game example: imagine a block starting at `NewStartPositionY` and ending at `NewEndPositionY`. We know `GroundLevel` is the ground height (you consider it as zero) and `CeilingLevel` is the ceiling height. A character might jump at most `MaxJump` units. Some other parameters might be `PlayerHeight`, which is the height of the character, and `LastStartPositionY` and `LastEndPositionY` which define the last block, and let's take `MinimumBlockSize` as the minimum size of platform. Knowing all these values you can set your boundaries :

```
// to initialize boundaries
NewStartPositionY = GroundLevel;
NewEndPositionT = min (LastEndPositionY + MaxJump,  CeilingLevel - PlayerHeight)
// to set actual random value
NewStartPositionY = random (NewEndPositionY - NewStartPositionY - MinimumBlockSize)
NewEndPositionY = random (NewEndPositionY - NewStartPositionY - MinimumBlockSize) + NewStartPositionY + MinimumBlockSize;
```

---

**Edit:**

Here is what the above code actually does; I just expanded it since it seems to cause many a headache! (It just needs more variables and does more operations but the result is the same.)

```
// -- first we define what are the boundaries of generated blocks 
// it's obvious that no block can be under the ground level
MinimumBoundaryY = GroundLevel;
// we need to make sure player can jump over the new level
// and at the same time we have to make sure player can go over it
// and not hit the ceiling so we choose the minimum value from them both
MaximumBoundaryY = min(lastEndPositionY + maxJump, CeilingLevel - PlayerHeight)
// --now initialize startPosition of the Block
// we want the block to at least have `MinimumBlockSize` height
// so the start position should be somewhere between `minimumBoundaryY`
// and `MaximumBoundaryY - MinimumBlockSize`
StartYRange = MaximumBoundaryY - MinimumBoundaryY - minimumBlockSize;
// and now we a random value we assign the actual value of new StartPosition
newStartPositionY = random() % StartYRange + MinimumBlockSize;
// --now as the last part we have to calculate endPosition of the new block
// again we first calculate the range for endPosition value.
// note that end position should always be somewhere between
// `beginPositionY + MinimumBlockHeight` and `maximumBlockHeight` so the range well be
EndYRange = MaximumBoundaryY - newStartPositionY - MinimumBlockHeight;
// in the end just set the EndPosition of the Block, we now it's variation range
// and we know it's the minimum valid value is `beginPositionY + MinimumBlockheight`
NewEndPositionY = random() % EndYRange + newStartPositionY + MinimumBlockHeight;
```

Hope this second piece of code helps you all understand what my code does! (and change your downvotes to upvotes :D).

Comment: I don't understand why this was chosen as the accepted answer. Why do you generate two random values? Also your `ys1` (which is the start position of the new block) can become bigger **or** smaller than `ye1` (it can even end up with the same size). Your example does something... but it doesn't position a block randomly, so that it's reachable by the player.

Comment: @bummzack: the error you specified is fixed now. and if there are going to be some platforms for the sake of game playability you have to reach to the next platform, and be able to pass over it (not hit the ceiling). i accept there are two values there are many games that all the platforms are floating in the sky and I prefer that ones much more. sure the ys0 value can always set to zero. that would make no real change in the algorithm.

Comment: @bummzack: the problem that you mentioned (ye1 < ys1) was just because of mispelling and i've fixed that. also now there is `ms` value for minimum size of platforms (so `ye1 - ys0 >= ms`) and the only reason that my answer was chosen was because i guess it had more details than the one cummonistduck gave not that his was wrong or mine was more usable. i'm just wondering why he has more votes than mine.

Comment: I really don't understand why this needs two random values. The Communist Duck's answer is much better.

Comment: @attackinghobo let's say when i was givving my answer i was thinking of a game like [hellicoper flash game](http://www.helicoptergame.net/) it's no big deal just remove ys values if you don't need it you don't have to downvote my answer!

Comment: @Gajet this seems incredibly complicated for what is a very simple idea..and your use of variable names is very confusing. I don't understand it.

Comment: Use variables that are descriptive, not cryptic.

Comment: "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live." — [Martin Golding](http://www.gdargaud.net/Humor/QuotesProgramming.html)

Comment: @TheCommunistDuck @Attackinghobo @martinGolding did you read my answer completely? I just described every variable is used for what and what they mean, then used them. but i'll just change their names so that won't be a problem any more.

Comment: @Gajet Why are you calculating ranges when the algorithm calls for only a single Y value? e.g. it would decide building height in [Canabalt](http://www.adamatomic.com/canabalt/). There is no start or end value, just a single point on the Y axis.

Comment: @Gajet, please check the revision history. It seems there was an edit collision and you might want to roll back the text, at least, to my version.

Answer (score 6):

@Gajet's answer is impossible to follow (so I'm not even convinced it will work), and what I think @The Communist Duck meant his solution to be...

```
block_y = ground_y + random() % (previousBlock_y + playerJumpHeight)
```

...will be heavily biased towards creating blocks with y-values centered around `ground_y + playerJumpHeight`.

The easiest way to produce more satisfying results would be, rather than generate a height between `ground_y` and `previousBlock_y + playerJumpHeight`, generate a random value between `previousBlock_y - playerJumpHeight` and `previousBlock_y + playerJumpHeight`.

Of course, since we want to take `ground_y` and `maxBlockHeight` into consideration also, we *really* want to find a random value between `max(ground_y, previousBlock_y - playerJumpHeight)` and `min(maxBlockHeight, previousBlock_y + playerJumpHeight)`.  This will skew our distribution a bit *(biased towards the center of the screen)*, but not enough to be noticeable.

The simplest way to do this would be

```
//delta_y is a random number between -/+ playerJumpHeight
min_y = max(ground_y, previousBlock_y - playerJumpHeight)
max_y = min(maxBlockHeight, previousBlock_y + playerJumpHeight)
range_y = max_y - min_y
block_y = random() % range_y + min_y
```

If you then want the block to have a random height as well, just generate a random number between `ground_y` and `block_y` to be the height.

---

**[Edit]**  There *is* a way to have a probability of jumping down by any amount, while still giving the player equal probability of being anywhere on the screen at any given point.

Thanks to [Didier Piau](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47494/magical-loaded-dice-and-expected-values) on the math forums for figuring this out.  The full explanation is complex, so I'll leave it out; the curious can visit that page, from which I generalized this algorithm.  The algorithm itself is actually pretty simple, though.

```
int getNextBlockHeight()
{
    int playingFieldHeight = screen_y - ground_y;
    int canonicalBlockMaxHeight = playingFieldHeight - playerHeight;
    int nextBlockMaxHeight = min(currentBlockHeight + playerJumpHeight, canonicalBlockMaxHeight);

    //Let's divide the screen vertically into chunks of size playerJumpHeight.
    //This code makes it so that each chunk is approximately twice as likely as being chosen
    //as the previous chunk
    float canonicalHeightRatio = (float)canonicalBlockMaxHeight / playerJumpHeight;
    float nextHeightRatio = (float)nextBlockMaxHeight / playerJumpHeight;

    //The following looks complicated, but really it just ensures that the minimum is 0, the maximum is
    //nextBlockMaxHeight, and everything in between is mapped logarithmically
    float randomMin = pow(2, -canonicalHeightRatio);
    float randomMax = pow(2, nextHeightRatio-canonicalHeightRatio);
    float randomVal = randFloat(randomMin, randomMax);
    float randomHeightRatio = log2(randVal)+canonicalHeightRatio;
    return (int)(randomHeightRatio*playerJumpHeight) + ground_y;
}

//Return the log-base-2 of a number
const float log_of_2 = log(2);
float log2(float value)
{
    return log(value) / log_of_2;
}

//Generates a random floating-point number between min and max
float randFloat(float min, float max)
{
    float randomNormalized = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX; //Between 0.0 and 1.0
    return randomNormalized*(max-min) + min;
}
```

Comment: hope you understand what my answer were (and why it was accepted) now.

Answer (score 4):

Generate a random `y` value between a ground y value `g` and a max height `m`. `m` is simply `g+character jump height`.

I don't know how Obj-C's random works, but usually you'll want something like:

`block_y = (random() % m) + g;`

Comment: `random() % m` produces non-uniform results. For a game it probably doesn't matter too much; on the other hand for a game the system rand()/random() functions may not be acceptable, and as long as you're going to deal with that you might as well do this part right too.

Comment: Since the OP is asking for Objective-C I'd suggest [arc4random](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html) as the random function.

Comment: -1 I think OP wanted both a random height off the ground AND a random block-height.  Even if he didn't, this will not work - it will always produce a value between `g` and `2*g + jumpHeight`.  And even if you fixed it to be say what I assume you meant (`m = previousBlockHeight + jumpHeight`), it would still produce unsatisfying results - it would be heavily biased towards generating blocks near the ground, meaning the character would rarely be near the top of the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Coincidentally, I [wrote a random number generator in Objective-C a few weeks ago to help teach myself the language](https://bitbucket.org/piman/objrand).

If you're using it, you can generate numbers between two values using the following messages on the `Random` class:

```
/* Inclusive low to exclusive high. */
- (int32_t)uniformIntFrom:(int32_t)low to:(int32_t)high;
- (uint32_t)uniformUnsignedFrom:(uint32_t)low to:(uint32_t)high;

/* Inclusive low to inclusive high. */
- (float)uniformFloatFrom:(float)low to:(float)high;
- (double)uniformDoubleFrom:(double)low to:(double)high;

/* Inclusive 0 to exclusive 1. */
- (float)uniformFloat;
- (double)uniformDouble;
```

If you are curious about how to generate a good random number between two values, [this is the main portion of the source code for it](https://bitbucket.org/piman/objrand/src/99c6c48aa9b5/ObjRand/Random.m#cl-64):

```
uint32_t range = high - low;
uint32_t reject;
uint32_t n;

if (range < 2)
    return low;

/* Trick borrowed from OpenBSD's arc4random_uniform. Figure out
 * the size of the bias given the requested range, and throw away
 * numbers within the biased range.
 */

if (range > 0x80000000)
    reject = 1 + ~range;
else
    reject = ((max - (range * 2)) + 1) % range;

do {
    n = [engine next];
} while (n < reject);
return low + (n % range);
```

Where `[engine next`] gives me a number between 0 and `max` (which is usually UINT_MAX, i.e. 2<sup>32</sup>-1).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how this translates in Obj-C but here's my version for C++. You want to normalize your random value before turning it into a specific range so the rand() stays uniform.

```
float randomHeight( float heightMin, float heightMax )
{
    float normRand = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
    float range = normRand * (heightMax - heightMin);
    return range + heightMin;
}
```

Note that rand() returns values from 0 to RAND_MAX so if you can find the equivalent in Obj-C, you can just replace these values with yours.

Comment: Same problem as @Communist Duck's answer, will generate blocks that are heavily biased towards the bottom of the screen - being near the top of the screen would be rare, especially if `playerJumpHeight` is small.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPtflughoeft: he has some value for his height min value. it makes his answer diffrent from the one CommunistDuck gave and more similar to mine. just by changeing `heightMin` in each cycle he will get out of hook.

Answer (score -3):

It sounds like what you want is just a 1D string of [Perlin Noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise).  This is a very well documented problem and there are several examples available on the internet.

Comment: I don't think it is. It doesn't account for jumping accessibility at all.

Comment: It gives you a value from 0.0 - 1.0 that varies in a nice distribution.  All you need to do is map that so that 0.0 is 0.0 and 1.0 is your max height!

Comment: so does random(), but this person is obviously confused about how to do it.

Comment: Perlin noise is a continuous, and thereby very non-random, distribution. All we need here is a random number between two values.